# How to change the timestamps in a column so that it is continuous, once I concatenate?

Tags: python, append, multiple-columns

``I am concatenating 3 csv files, where each records 10 minutes of data.  The files each contain about 73000 rows; 10 minute recordings with sampling rate = 12000 points (Hz).

The signal has been [decimated] by a factor of 100 (which is why there are 73000 rows, opposed to 7300000) and 6 columns, where Column 2 = Time(s). The difference between row2-row1=0.008203 sec.

Each file contains row 0 till row ~73169. I am able to concatenate all the files into a single .csv file. The time series looks like 0.086092 till 600.260394 (sec) and the next one starts from 0.086092 till 599.784587 (sec).

There are 2 values in the last row, column 3, 4 are missing (blank cells) and the following row starts from 0.086091 till 600.301452 (sec).

How can I make the time series continuous and fill those blank cells in the adjacent columns?

```py
filenames = ['Desktop/1.csv, Desktop/2.csv, Desktop/3.csv']
dataframes = []
for filename in filenames:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=1))
    frame = pd.concat(dataframes)
    frame.to_csv('Desktop/concatenate.csv')
```

screen shot: 
Column B = time in sec

[image: Column B = time in sec.. please note blank rows]

Attached is the code that I used to solve.. appreciate any suggestions.. [here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgEgF.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to include a text copy of the head and tail of the dataframe because the question is unclear in regards to the 2 values in the last row.

Comment: It looks like the first csv is missing some data points.  You should load each csv into a separate dataframe  to explore.  That should help you determine what's causing the missing data points.  You have stated the data is preprocessed (decimated / resampled), which may be the cause.  What does the data look like before it's resampled?

Comment: Hello Trenton_M, was able to solve it after a long and slow learning curve..

Comment: You can provide an answer to your own question on SO.

Comment: I am trying to paste the code.. but it seems long..

Comment: Only include the minimal code to resolve the error and include a verbal explanation.